# Dynamic dependency injection

Tags: c#, dynamic, dependency-injection

## Second approach

I have a family of applications that offer an extensible (i.e. not fixed) set of variables which can be used by various plugins.

Examples are:

1. A source for log events
2. A source of computation results
3. A source for system resource usage
4. A source for performace indicators
5. ...

Plugins may use any combination of these.

Sample plugins could be:

- A custom error logger, using 1.
- A custom statistic module, using 2.
- A performace tool using 3. and 4.

What I want to achieve is to

- present a list of plugins that can be used given a set of variables present in this application (when there is no log event source, you should not be able to select the custom error logger).
- get a simple and safe to use way to pass the variables to the plugins so that there is no chance for runtime errors due to missing variables.

A bonus would be to allow plugins to optionally require a variable, e.g. a plugin that requires 4. and optionally uses 3. if available (but is also available otherwise).

## First approach

I want to implement some kind of "dynamic dependency injection".
Let me explain it with a use case.

I'm building a set of libraries that will be used for a family of applications.
Each application can provide a different set of variables which are available to certain "handlers" in need of these variables.
Depending on the concrete available variables, the number of available handlers must be determined, since handlers can only be used if they have access to all required variables.
Also I'm looking for a way to make the invocation as safe as possible.
Compile-time will probably not possible, but "check once, never fails afterwards" would be fine.

Below is a first sketch. Everything can still be changed in this stage.

```
class DynamicDependencyInjectionTest
{
    private ISomeAlwaysPresentClass a;
    private ISomeOptionalClass optionA;
    private ISomeOtherOptionalClass optionB;
    private ISomeMultipleOption[] multi;

    private IDependentFunction dependentFunction;

    void InvokeDependency()
    {
        // the number of available dependencies varies.
        // some could be guaranteed, others are optional, some maybe have several instances
        var availableDependencies = new IDependencyBase[] {a, optionA, optionB}.Concat(multi).ToArray();
        //var availableDependencies = new IDependencyBase[] { a  };
        //var availableDependencies = new IDependencyBase[] { a, optionA }.ToArray();
        //var availableDependencies = new IDependencyBase[] { a, optionB }.ToArray();
        //var availableDependencies = new IDependencyBase[] { a , multi.First() };

        //ToDo
        // this is what I want to do
        // since we checked it before, this must always succeed
        somehowInvoke(dependentFunction, availableDependencies);

    }

    void SetDependentFunction(IDependentFunction dependentFunction)
    {
        if (! WeCanUseThisDependentFunction(dependentFunction))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        this.dependentFunction = dependentFunction;
    }

    private bool WeCanUseThisDependentFunction(IDependentFunction dependentFunction)
    {
        //ToDo
        //check if we can fulfill the requested dependencies
        return true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Provide a list which can be used by the user (e.g. selected from a combobox)
    /// </summary>
    IDependentFunction[] AllDependentFunctionsAvailableForThisApplication()
    {
        IDependentFunction[] allDependentFunctions = GetAllDependentFunctionsViaReflection();
        return allDependentFunctions.Where(WeCanUseThisDependentFunction).ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all possible candidates
    /// </summary>
    private IDependentFunction[] GetAllDependentFunctionsViaReflection()
    {
        var types = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof (IDependentFunction).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToArray();

        var instances = types.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IDependentFunction).ToArray();
        return instances;
    }


    private void somehowInvoke(IDependentFunction dependentFunction, IDependencyBase[] availableDependencies)
    {
        //ToDo
    }
}

// the interfaces may of course by changed!

/// <summary>
/// Requires a default constructor
/// </summary>
interface IDependentFunction
{
    void Invoke(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass a, IDependencyBase[] dependencies);
    Type[] RequiredDependencies { get; }
}

interface IDependencyBase { }
interface ISomeAlwaysPresentClass : IDependencyBase { }
interface ISomeOptionalClass : IDependencyBase { }
interface ISomeOtherOptionalClass : IDependencyBase { }
interface ISomeMultipleOption : IDependencyBase { }


class BasicDependentFunction : IDependentFunction
{
    public void Invoke(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass a, IDependencyBase[] dependencies)
    {
        ;
    }

    public Type[] RequiredDependencies
    {
        get { return new[] {typeof(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass)}; }
    }
}

class AdvancedDependentFunction : IDependentFunction
{
    public void Invoke(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass a, IDependencyBase[] dependencies)
    {
        ;
    }

    public Type[] RequiredDependencies
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass), typeof(ISomeOptionalClass) }; }
    }
}

class MaximalDependentFunction : IDependentFunction
{
    public void Invoke(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass a, IDependencyBase[] dependencies)
    {
        ;
    }

    public Type[] RequiredDependencies
    {
        // note the array in the type of ISomeMultipleOption[]
        get { return new[] { typeof(ISomeAlwaysPresentClass), typeof(ISomeOptionalClass), typeof(ISomeOtherOptionalClass), typeof(ISomeMultipleOption[]) }; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As Mark's answer implies, you should respect the KISS principle and don't try to reinvent the wheel with some obscure DI. Think of those who will read your code. Even you in some months can get headaches to understand what you intend in the first place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple. Let plugins rely on **Constructor Injection**, which has the advantage that constructors statically announce each class' dependencies. Then use Reflection to figure out what you can create.

Assume, for example, that you have three Services:

```
public interface IFoo { }

public interface IBar { }

public interface IBaz { }
```

Assume, furthermore, that three plugins exist:

```
public class Plugin1
{
    public readonly IFoo Foo;

    public Plugin1(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.Foo = foo;
    }
}

public class Plugin2
{
    public readonly IBar Bar;
    public readonly IBaz Baz;

    public Plugin2(IBar bar, IBaz baz)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
        this.Baz = baz;
    }
}

public class Plugin3
{
    public readonly IBar Bar;
    public readonly IBaz Baz;

    public Plugin3(IBar bar)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public Plugin3(IBar bar, IBaz baz)
    {
        this.Bar = bar; ;
        this.Baz = baz;
    }
}
```

It's clear that `Plugin1` requires `IFoo`, and `Plugin2` requires `IBar` and `IBaz`. The third class, `Plugin3`, is a bit more special, because it has an optional dependency. While it *requires* `IBar`, it can also use `IBaz` if it's available.

You can define a Composer that uses some basic reflection to examine whether or not it'd be possible to create instances of various plugins, based on available services:

```
public class Composer
{
    public readonly ISet<Type> services;

    public Composer(ISet<Type> services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public Composer(params Type[] services) :
        this(new HashSet<Type>(services))
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetAvailableClients(params Type[] candidates)
    {
        return candidates.Where(CanCreate);
    }

    private bool CanCreate(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetConstructors().Any(CanCreate);
    }

    private bool CanCreate(ConstructorInfo ctor)
    {
        return ctor.GetParameters().All(p => 
            this.services.Contains(p.ParameterType));
    }
}
```

As you can see, you configure a `Composer` instance with a set of available Services, and you can then call the `GetAvailableClients` method with a list of candidates to get a sequence of available plugins.

You can easily expand the `Composer` class to also be able to create instances of the desired plugins, instead of only telling you which ones are available.

You may be able to find this feature already available in some DI Containers. IIRC, Castle Windsor exposes a *Tester/Doer* API, and I wouldn't be surprised if MEF supports such a feature as well.

The following xUnit.net Parametrised Test demonstrates that the above `Composer` works.

```
public class Tests
{
    [Theory, ClassData(typeof(TestCases))]
    public void AllServicesAreAvailable(
        Type[] availableServices,
        Type[] expected)
    {
        var composer = new Composer(availableServices);
        var actual = composer.GetAvailableClients(
            typeof(Plugin1), typeof(Plugin2), typeof(Plugin3));
        Assert.True(new HashSet<Type>(expected).SetEquals(actual));
    }
}

internal class TestCases : IEnumerable<Object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IFoo), typeof(IBar), typeof(IBaz) },
            new[] { typeof(Plugin1), typeof(Plugin2), typeof(Plugin3) }
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IBar), typeof(IBaz) },
            new[] { typeof(Plugin2), typeof(Plugin3) }
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IFoo), typeof(IBaz) },
            new[] { typeof(Plugin1) }
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IFoo), typeof(IBar) },
            new[] { typeof(Plugin1), typeof(Plugin3) }
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IFoo) },
            new[] { typeof(Plugin1) }
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IBar) },
            new[] { typeof(Plugin3) }
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new[] { typeof(IBaz) },
            new Type[0]
        };
        yield return new object[] {
            new Type[0],
            new Type[0]
        };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and your excellent book. In the meantime I found a solution which depends on some kind of property injection but constructor injection is superior in this case. The `Composer` helps me figuring out which plugin is usable, but I still have to do the actual instantiation. Can I achieve this by using a standard DI container and using - to stay with Castle Windsor - by registering `IFoo` with `Component.For<IFoo>().Instance(myClass.instanceOfIFoo)`? And if I do this, could I also replace the Composer with a Castle Windsor "test" function?

Comment: @Onur It'd make sense to leverage an existing library like Castle Windsor to implement both 'CanCreate' and 'Create' functionality; I mostly added the `Composer` class to my answer in order to demonstrate the principle. As long as a DI Container like Castle Windsor can answer the question *can you create an object of this type?* you should be able to implement the desired functionality. It's been a while since I seriously used any DI Container, so I can't remember the API details, but IIRC several DI Containers can answer such a question.

Comment: I managed to get a prototype running with Castle.Windsor based on your ideas (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Lessons learned:

1. Originally I thought I would need a per call method injection which is complicated because:

   - It's harder to tell if the dependencies can be fulfilled before instantiating the class
   - The method signature is either not fully typesafe or not part of a (nongeneric) interface.
   - Although it's possible it's nonstandard and thus not easily supported by existing systems
2. Then I switched to a kind of property injection by adding the required dependencies as properties, each tied to an interface, so that the required dependencies could easily be discovered. The invocation itself was parameterless.

   - This made it easier to find out which plugin could be used.
   - A chain of "if this plugin implements the interface for setting the property of this dependency, set it" statements could fill in the dependencies before calling the parameterless method.
   - If one call was omitted, the dependency would have not been set.
3. Probably the right way to do is using constructor injection, so one can use standard tools. The invocation itself is also parameterless, so it will fit nicely in an interface.

Below is a more complete version of  Mark's solution, including resolving a component. It uses Castle.Windsor, xUnit, Shouldly and Resharper's `NotNull, CanBeNull` attributes.

Further work is necessary to remove the direct dependency upon Castle.Windsor by injecting a resolving facility factory (since it must accept the instances from the host, we cannot pass in the resolver directly).

```
public interface IFoo { }

public interface IBar { }

public interface IBaz { }

/// <summary>
/// Needed to invoke the plugin
/// </summary>
public interface IPlugin
{
    void Invoke();
}

public class Plugin1 : IPlugin
{
    public readonly IFoo Foo;

    public Plugin1([NotNull] IFoo foo)
    {
        if (foo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
        this.Foo = foo;
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        ;
    }
}

public class Plugin2 : IPlugin
{
    public readonly IBar Bar;
    public readonly IBaz Baz;

    public Plugin2([NotNull] IBar bar, [NotNull] IBaz baz)
    {
        if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
        if (baz == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("baz");
        this.Bar = bar;
        this.Baz = baz;
    }
    public void Invoke()
    {
        ;
    }
}

public class Plugin3 : IPlugin
{
    public readonly IBar Bar;
    public readonly IBaz Baz;

    public Plugin3([NotNull] IBar bar, [CanBeNull] IBaz baz = null)
    {
        if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
        this.Bar = bar; ;
        this.Baz = baz;
    }
    public void Invoke()
    {
        ;
    }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
}

public class SampleHostTest
{


    [Fact]
    void SampleHostCanResolvePlugin3ButNot1And2()
    {

        var bar = new Bar();
        var plugins = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SampleHost))
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .ToArray();

        var sut = new SampleHost(bar, plugins);

        sut.IsPluginSupported(typeof(Plugin1)).ShouldBeFalse();
        sut.IsPluginSupported(typeof(Plugin2)).ShouldBeFalse();
        sut.IsPluginSupported(typeof(Plugin3)).ShouldBeTrue();
    }

    [Fact]
    void ResolvePlugin3()
    {

        var bar = new Bar();
        var plugins = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SampleHost))
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .ToArray();

        var sut = new SampleHost(bar, plugins);

        sut.IsPluginSupported(typeof(Plugin3)).ShouldBeTrue();

        sut.CreateAndInvokePlugin(typeof(Plugin3));
        // no exception => succeeded
    }



}

public class SampleHost
{
    private readonly IBar bar;
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
    private Type[] plugins;

    public SampleHost(IBar bar, IEnumerable<Type> plugins)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.plugins = plugins.ToArray();
        this.container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<IBar>().Instance(this.bar));

        foreach (var plugin in this.plugins)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For(plugin).ImplementedBy(plugin).LifestyleTransient());
        }
    }

    public bool IsPluginSupported(Type type)
    {
        var result = container.Kernel.HasComponent(type) &&
                     container.Kernel.GetHandler(type).CurrentState == HandlerState.Valid;
        return result;
    }

    public void CreateAndInvokePlugin(Type type)
    {
        Assert.True(IsPluginSupported(type));

        var plugin = container.Resolve(type)as IPlugin;

        Debug.Assert(plugin != null, "plugin != null");
        plugin.Invoke();
    }


}
```